# How this regular expression work?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to understand how this regular expression (aka regex) stored in "regex" variable works?

```
regex='^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$'
```

I am new to bash scripting and having hard time work with regular expression!

Numbers from 1-9, 0-9, 0-4 and 0-5 are repeated at least twice, which is creating confusion!
Thank you!

Comment: The regex is explained here: https://regex101.com/r/sP6eQ8/1

Comment: What I want to understand is how this will work if we use it against a text file! Lets say I have a text file called "file1.txt". How is this regular expression going to compare the text file!

Comment: That depends on what is *using* the regular expression, but typically something like `grep` will use the regular expression to output those lines from "file1.txt" that match it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this part alone:

```
[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]
```

It's a series of alternatives (separated by `|`), here on separate lines:

```
[1-9]                # Matches 1-9
[1-9][0-9]           # Matches 10-99
1[0-9][0-9]          # Matches 100-199
2[0-4][0-9]          # Matches 200-249
25[0-5]              # Matches 250-255
```

In other words, it matches any number from 1 to 255 inclusive. It's a bit roundabout because regex has no concept of numbers, only of character strings.

The regex attempts to match a four of these numbers with periods between, in order to match a whole IPv4 address.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer! 1-9 is simple! From what I understand "[1-9][0-9]" matches 10-99 because in first bracket we match 1-9 and in second we match 0-9. In third portion we have 1[0-9][0-9] which matches 100-199 because we put "1" before both brackets! Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone was trying to match an IPv4 address. The group

```
([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

Matches a number from 1 to 255, it then matches a number from 0 to 255 three more times.

```
(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}
```

They tried to separate the four numbers with dots. The original regex you posted didn't escape the "`.`" so it would match any character between the four groups. Someone has since edited the regex to fix that character.

The regex is wrapped in `^` and `$` to make sure the string contains that and only that. `^` matches the beginning of a string. `$` matches the end.